# replace wicket 6.3 jquery

Tags: java, jquery, wicket

After migration to wicket 6.3, I encountered an error in console of developertools in chrome on pages that use jquery.
it seems that the jquery that wicket 6.3 use built-in, contains some link to rvzr-a.akamaihd.net.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) http://rvzr-a.akamaihd.net/amz/aeyJhZmZpZCI6MTAxOCwic3ViYWZmaWQiOjEwMjIsImh…2h0Ijo3NjgsImxvYWRlcl9jbGllbnRfdGltZXN0YW1wIjoxMzc2MzY2MTU0MTAxfQ%3D%3D.js
```

Comment: I've checked out wicket 6.3 sources and failed to uncover any reference to the URL you provided. Check your sources correctly, as it appears something else has this link in it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can provide Wicket with your own version of JQuery as described on http://wicket.apache.org/. In you application class, override the init method like so:

```
@Override 
protected void init() {
    getJavaScriptLibrarySettings().setJQueryReference(new UrlResourceReference(Url.parse("http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js")));
}
```

(you can pick other versions of JQuery from http://cdnjs.com/)

That being said I'm skeptical Wicket would have references to rvzr-a.akamaihd.net.