# Wicket 6 remove JQuery reference

Tags: jquery, wicket

I need to turn off wicket's JQuery autoimport. Because I use hash navigation and load pages using ajax, and wicket loads JQuery every time, and it breaks all jquery plugins I added before.
Application's init method:

```
getJavaScriptLibrarySettings().setJQueryReference(null);
```

Doesn't work, application just doesn't start.
One solution to add empty javascript. If I have empty.js in my web/js folder, how can I set it as JQueryReference?

Comment: instead of removing the jquery reference of wicket, you could just replace it with another one as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18200451/replace-wicket-6-3-jquery

Comment: You can also replace it with an empty file and import the real code some other way, if that is what you require.

Answer (score 2):

Just add a new file called `empty.js` next to `MyWicketApplication.java`, and add this line in your applications's init method:

```
getJavaScriptLibrarySettings().setJQueryReference(new PackageResourceReference(MyWicketApplication.class,"empty.js"));
```